# Deserialize Json from REST api and use the Values gotten from the Json

Tags: c#, json, rest

So when Working on a JSON Deserializer, I wanted to do something like this get the Values retrieved from a REST Webservice and made it into a Json Object.
So this works perfect, no troubles

So far, My the Json retrieved Looks like this :

```
{\"Fullname\":\"John Snow\",\"Telephone\":\"08147720192\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"email\":\"john.snow@gmail.com\",\"date_ofbirth\":\"1985-06-22T00:00:00\",\"nationalID\":\"JS834788US\",\"accountnumber\":\"0034773291\",\"salary\":800000.00}
```

Now here is the worry, I would want to retrieve the values from a Deserialized Json and then Set the values, So it can be used in another application. I am building it in form of a Class Library.

Now like I said before I have been able to Make one, Which returns the Data into Json. Now i want to Deserialize and then use the values gotten from the REST api in another web application

The Code for the Deseializer looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Deserializer
{
    public class EmpPersonalInfo 
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string date_ofbirth { get; set; }
        public string nationalID { get; set; }
        public string accountnumber { get; set; }
        public decimal salary { get; set; }
    }
    public class RESTJSONDeserializer
    {
        public static void Deserializer(string JSON) 
        {
            EmpPersonalInfo account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpPersonalInfo>(JSON);
            //Get and set the Values here
        }
    }
}
```

The primary challenge is I have never worked on something like this before. So for the sake of clarity, I would need some Explanation and guidance as to code something like this

Thanks

Comment: `Deserializer` return void.. change the return type and return account .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class RESTJSONDeserializer
    {
        public static EmpPersonalInfo Deserializer(string JSON) 
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpPersonalInfo>(JSON);
            //Get and set the Values here
        }
    }
```

this class should like this and when u need the deserialize object u can simply call this method

```
EmpPersonalInfo model= RESTJSONDeserializer.Deserializer("JsonFromApi");
```

Comment: Should i want to return the values So i can use in another application how do i go about that??

Comment: Now i want to set the value to an object say a string for instance. So that i can use that same string in my application. Thats what i want now

Comment: I thank you so Much! You made my Day! God bless you!!!!!! Thanks its working now